# How to make this script to quickly set specific weights?

Tags: python, scripting, weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I have an idea how to get a faster workflow when assigning weights in edit mode, and would like to know how hard this would be to make in python as an addon:

**Before: I'm manually setting weights using this method:**

1. Select one or more vertices
2. Select a vertex group
3. Choose a weight, by entering 0.2 and pressing enter
4. Click Assign

If I'm not happy with it, repeat 3-4 until I'm happy. This can be quite cumbersome and a lot of clicking and typing.

**After: With my addon, it would be one less step, like this:**

1. Select one or more vertices
2. Select a vertex group
3. Click 20 - And 0.2 is assigned in one click

If I'm not happy with it, I just click another value. It would save a lot of time for me.

And as an extra bonus, if this is possible, there is also a **Liveweight slider**, that updates the vertex group as I drag the slider, and I see the result right away. Pretty much like the Vertex weights in the Properties panel, but this affects all selected vertices.

Would this be possible, and where would I start? I have never coded anything in python, but I've been coding for a long time, mostly PHP and Javascript, so I think I can figure out the basics, if I get some pointers.

Also, is it possible to put this inside the Vertex Group section, or does it need to be in a separate panel?

Here's a rough screenshot of my idea as a separate panel, sorry for a weird number of buttons

[image]

Here's the code I've made so far. I got it working when I had another similar script loaded, but when I use only this, I only get the Panel, not the buttons. Is there a class I missed or something?

Now I'd be happy for some tips on finding the active vertex group and assigning the vertex values to the selected vertices.

I tried to implement the code, but I'm not sure if I should tab in the for loop, and make it iterate through all vertices.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Quickly set weights of Vertex Groups",
    "author": "nicmar",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 78, 0),
    "location": "Properties Editor > Object data > Vertex Groups",
    "description": "Quickly set Vertex Groups with assigned weight and live edit",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Mesh"}

import bpy
import time

from bpy.types import Panel

class QuickWeightPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Quick Vertex Weights"
    bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES";
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW";
    bl_context = "data"
    #bl_category = "Test"
       
    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.alignment = 'EXPAND'
        row.operator("my.button", text="0").number=0
        row.operator("my.button", text="10").number=0.1
        row.operator("my.button", text="25").number=0.25
        row.operator("my.button", text="40").number=0.4
        row.operator("my.button", text="50").number=0.5
        row.operator("my.button", text="60").number=0.6
        row.operator("my.button", text="75").number=0.75
        row.operator("my.button", text="90").number=0.9
        row.operator("my.button", text="100").number=1


class MyOp(bpy.types.Operator): #The operator class derived from Operator
    bl_idname="my.button" #Same as in row.operator
    bl_label="my.button blabla" #Needed

    number=bpy.props.FloatProperty() #The property used in row.operator

    def execute(self, context): #Is trigered by buttons


        # Toggle into edit mode
        obj=bpy.context.active_object
        
        # Toggle into object mode (Wrong? I need to be in edit mode to set weights?)
        #prevMode = obj.mode
        #bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT', toggle=False)

        # Get active vertex group index
        active_vertex_group_index = obj.vertex_groups.active_index

        # Should I use this?
        #g=obj.vertex_groups['group name']
        
        # Loop through and get all selected vertices i v (?)
        [v for v in obj.data.vertices if v.select] 
        # Get first?
        v = obj.data.vertices[0]
        # Get the data for the group accessed by the group index 
        vg=v.groups[active_vertex_group_index]
        # Set weight of active vertices in active weight group
        # vg.weight = 0.5
        # Print weight of current vertex
        print(vg.weight) 
        
        # Return to previous mode before operator 
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=prevMode, toggle=False)

        return {'FINISHED'}     


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    #bpy.types.Data.ignit_panel = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=IgnitProperties)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    #del bpy.types.Data.ignit_panel


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I don't get the point of having this extra panel? so what if my value wasn't one of the 0,10,25...100 buttons? and how do you expect to set the Liveweight as it looks to me exactly like the weight in the vertexgroups panel?

Comment: When I for example set up a finger I want to use 50/50 for the mid joint, 75/25 for the next edge loop and so on. And commonly for rigging I dont't think I would need more fine values than these, but if I meed another I can just enter it. Also the live weight updates the values as I pull, opposed to Weight where I need to press Assign each time which is slower.

Comment: Niclas, reading your question, the answer may be either a complete tutorial on how to code these functions or a "I do it for you" answer (and of course, this is matter of free time to do it). So yes, what you describe can be done. First of all, have a look at the documentation https://docs.blender.org/api/2.78b/info_tutorial_addon.html and please ask more specific questions if you meet some issues

Comment: Sorry, I added the code I have made so far. The specific questions at this point is 1) Why isn't the buttons showing up 2) How do I find the active vertex group and assigning the vertex values to the selected vertices.

Comment: You need to declare properties on your operator. See for instance https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Operator.html. Here the operator will correspond to "my.button" (bl_idname="my.button") and "number" is the declared property in the operator class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that can save you some time. See the commented part below:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Quickly set weights of Vertex Groups",
    "author": "nicmar",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 78, 0),
    "location": "Properties Editor > Object data > Vertex Groups",
    "description": "Quickly set Vertex Groups with assigned weight and live edit",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Mesh"}

import bpy
import time
from bpy.types import Panel

class QuickWeightPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Quick Vertex Weights"
    bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES";
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW";
    bl_context = "data"
    #bl_category = "Tomte"

    def draw(self,context):

        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.alignment = 'EXPAND'
        
        row.operator("my.button", text="0").number=0
        row.operator("my.button", text="10").number=0.1
        row.operator("my.button", text="25").number=0.25
        row.operator("my.button", text="40").number=0.4
        row.operator("my.button", text="50").number=0.5
        row.operator("my.button", text="60").number=0.6
        row.operator("my.button", text="75").number=0.75
        row.operator("my.button", text="90").number=0.9
        row.operator("my.button", text="100").number=1

class MyOp(bpy.types.Operator): #The operator class derived from Operator
    bl_idname="my.button" #Same as in row.operator
    bl_label="my.button blabla" #Needed
    
    number=bpy.props.FloatProperty() #The property used in row.operator

    def execute(self, context): #Is trigered by buttons
        print("Test", self.number) #With the associated value
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

To go further on the addon:

- Active object and its type

`obj=bpy.context.active_object`

`obj.type` needs to be `'MESH'`

- Object groups

`obj.vertex_groups` contains the groups.

Use `obj.vertex_groups.new(...)` to create one or `remove(...)` to remove

`g=obj.vertex_groups['group name']`

`g.index` used in vertices (see below)

`obj.vertex_groups.active_index` is the currently selected group in the property panel

- Object data

`obj.data` all object inner data

`obj.data.vertices` its vertices

`[v for v in obj.data.vertices if v.select]` selected vertices

`v = obj.data.vertices[0]`

`v.groups` contains the weights for each group `v` is involved in

`vg=v.groups[groupIndex]` the data for the group accessed by the group index

`vg.weight` is the weight

You'll probably need something like

```
prevMode = obj.mode

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT', toggle=False)

#... your code here

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=prevMode, toggle=False)
```

To retrieve safely the selected vertices and come back to the mode selected before script execution.

Comment: Thanks, that helped to get the script running. I will fiddle some more with actually implementing the actions to edit the mesh and weights. This question was maybe a bit to broad :) But I'm not sure if I should accept this as an answer or not as it only partly answers my issue. Don't want anyone making it all for me though since I want to learn too...

Comment: @Niclas, never mind about upvoting or accepting. I will simply add some elements that could be useful

Comment: I tried it, and I at least got the index of the selected vertex group. I have a few problems, I updated my code above. I don't understand if there's a for loop going on, and how `[v for v in obj.data.vertices if v.select]` works. I tried to add comments to what I think it's doing. If you're able to check I'll be very happy. Thanks again!

Comment: Brilliant, it worked. The code was very clear. I had to add one line, weightToAssign = self.number. It can probably be improved in many ways, but you have taught me the basics of python in a very effective way. Thanks again - Answer accepted :)

Comment: This didn't work for me. Just keeps telling me the operator object has no attribute 'number'. Problem with the newer versions of Blender?

Answer (score 0):

In the newer versions of blender you need to use a colon symbol instead of equal symbol operator.

So the operator from the example above becomes:

```
class MyOp(bpy.types.Operator): 
bl_idname="my.button" 
bl_label="my.button blabla" 

number : bpy.props.FloatProperty() # Equal symbol is changed to colon

def execute(self, context): 
    print("Test", self.number) 
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

(This is an answer to the comment made by Gary, but I don't have enough reputation to comment)