# Multiple buttons assigned to the same Operator class

Tags: operator

Does every new button need to be assigned to a different operator class or can you assign multiple buttons to the same class to do different things.  Here is the code.  This panel is located in the Video Sequence editor.

```
import bpy



class CustomPanel(bpy.types.Panel):  
    bl_label = "Left, Right Button Test"
    bl_space_type = "SEQUENCE_EDITOR"  
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}

    def draw(self, context):

        def add_center_button():
            row = self.layout.row(align=True)
            row.operator("sequencer.center_images", text="Center A")
            row.operator("sequencer.center_images", text="Center B")


        add_center_button()


class Center_Images(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "sequencer.center_images"
    bl_label = "Center"

    def execute(self, context):
        print("Center button is being executed")

        return {'FINISHED'}






def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Have a look at the usage of the operator's "number" property here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75814/how-to-make-this-script-to-quickly-set-specific-weights-screenshot-attached/75851#75851

Comment: That cleared things up along with how bpy.props.Properties works in one fell swoop!